# digital image read as an array of integers

Tags: python, image-processing

Using `Python`'s `PIL` module, we can read an digital image into an `array` of integers,

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import array

img = Image.open('x.jpg')
im = array(img)  # im is the array representation of x.jpg
```

I wonder how does `PIL` interpret an image as an `array`? First I tried this

```
od -tu1 x.jpg
```

and it indeed gave a sequence of numbers, but how does `PIL` interpret a color image into a 3D array?

In short, my question is that I want to know how can I get a color image's array representation without using any module like `PIL`, how could do the job using Python?

Comment: Not certain what your question really is; what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends on the image format I would say.

For a .jpg, there is a complete description of the format that permits to read the image .
You can read it **[here](http://www.jpeg.org/public/jfif.pdf)**

What PIL does is exactly what you did at first. But then it reads the bytes following the specifications, which allow it to transform this into a human readable format (in this case an array).

It may seem complex for JPEG, but if you take png (the version without compression) everything can seem way more simple. 
[For example this image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4286043/SO/binary.png)

[image: png image without compression]

If you open it, you will see something like that : 
[image: Raw dump of previous png image]

You can see several information on top that corresponds to the header.

Then you see all those zeroes, that are the numerical representation of black pixels of the image (the top left corner).

If you open the image with PIL, you will get an array that is mostly filled with 0.

If you want to know more about the first bytes, look at the [png **specifications**](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) chapter 11.2.2.

You will see that some of the bytes corresponds to the width and height of the image. This is how PIL is able to create the array :).

Hope this helps !

Comment: ;) Let me know if something is missing

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the color mode. In PIL an image is stored as a list of integers with all channels interleaved on a per-pixel basis.

To illustrate this:

- Grayscale image: [pixel1, pixel2, pixel3, ...]
- RGB: [pixel1_R, pixel1_G, pixel1_B, pixel2_R, pixel_2_G, ...]
- Same goes for RBGA and so on.