# Convert JPEG blob into an image

Tags: python-3.x, image, blob

I get values from the Oracle blob, below.
It's a JPEG file that somebody stored as a signed char, rather than unsigned.
How can I convert it into a image?

```
[-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-37,0,67,0,1,...]
```

[View raw data on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/Y141317A)

Comment: Actually it's a JPEG file that somebody has stored as a signed char, rather than unsigned.

Comment: You might be able to [read a raw image using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3397157/924299), but specifics will probably depend on the [colorspace and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397322/924299) as well as the [image format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14319467/924299).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether you mean you want to save the data to disk as a JPEG or further process it in memory as an image.

As it is, the image has been (incorrectly) stored as a signed char instead of as an unsigned char - I can tell that because there are negative values in there. I can tell it is a JPEG because [JPEGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_files) have the string `JFIF` near the start and J=74, F=70 and I=73 in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table.svg) - you will see those values near the start.

So, first I did a list comprehension to correct the values like this:

```
# Data from pastebin
im = [-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0...]

# Correct negative values to be "256+current"
corrected = [256+x if x<0 else x for x in im]
```

Then, assuming you want to write the image to disk, it is already JPEG-encoded so we just need to convert the list to bytes and write those to disk

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Data from pastebin
im = [-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0 ...]

# Correct negative values to be "256+current"
corrected = [256+x if x<0 else x for x in im]

# Convert corrected data to bytes and save to disk as "result.jpg"
with open('result.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(corrected))
```

If, on the other hand, you want to make a **PIL** `Image` and process it, you can wrap the bytes in a `BytesIO` and ask **PIL** to open that:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Data from pastebin
im = [-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0 ...]

# Correct negative values to be "256+current"
corrected = [256+x if x<0 else x for x in im]

# Convert the corrected list to "bytes", wrap in BytesIO and ask PIL to open as PIL Image
pImage = Image.open(BytesIO(bytes(corrected)))

# Now we can display it
pImage.show() 

# Or save it
pImage.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

Note that if you prefer to use **OpenCV** rather than **PIL**, you would use `cv2.imdecode()` in place of **PIL** `Image.open()`.

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, convert list of numbers to image, convert blob to image, convert Oracle database blob to image.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now :)

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project! Come back and ask another question if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free :-)